# Counts of category by group

Tags: r, data.table, grouping, summary

One variable in my data is a categorical variable. I would like to compute the counts per category by group. My data has the following structure:

```
dt <- data.table("fact"=c(2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3), "month"=rep(1:5, 6), "id"=c(rep("a", 15), rep("b", 15)))
```

After the operation, the data should look as follows:

```
dt1 <- data.table("id" = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)), "month" = rep(1:5,2), 
"fact1" = c(0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
"fact2" = c(3,2,0,0,0,3,1,0,0,0),
"fact3" = c(0,1,1,3,3,0,2,2,3,3))
```

Note that fact1, fact2, fact3 are the levels in the categorical variable fact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a new character-vector column by pasting "fact" with the value in the fact column, and casting to wide format:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table("fact"=c(2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,3,3,3,3), "month"=rep(1:5, 6), "id"=c(rep("a", 15), rep("b", 15)))

dt[, name := paste("fact", fact, sep="")]
dcast(dt, id+month~name, value.var="name")
```

yields

```
    id month fact1 fact2 fact3
 1:  a     1     0     3     0
 2:  a     2     0     2     1
 3:  a     3     2     0     1
 4:  a     4     0     0     3
 5:  a     5     0     0     3
 6:  b     1     0     3     0
 7:  b     2     0     1     2
 8:  b     3     1     0     2
 9:  b     4     0     0     3
10:  b     5     0     0     3
```

Comment: It looks like this approach also works without creating a new column: `dcast(dt, id+month~paste0("fact",fact), value.var="fact")`